# Jssor slider: how to remove highlighting animation from thumbnail navigator

Tags: jssor

When you click on thumbnail image on thumbnail navigator, there is animation which goes to an image highlighting each image until it reaches the clicked thumbnail. I would like to remove the highlighting effect of the other thumbnails. I tried changing different options on thumbnail navigator, but I couldn't remove this effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thumbnail animations are specified by css3 transition. For example, you can see css in 'skin\thumbnail-08.source.html' as below,

```
            .jssort08 .o
            {
                ...

                border: 1px solid #000;

                transition: border-color .6s;
                -moz-transition: border-color .6s;
                -webkit-transition: border-color .6s;
                -o-transition: border-color .6s;
            }
```

You can remove the following code to disable the animation,

```
                transition: border-color .6s;
                -moz-transition: border-color .6s;
                -webkit-transition: border-color .6s;
                -o-transition: border-color .6s;
```

Comment: This is great for getting rid of border animation. But What I want is when you click on a thumbnail, to just go to the clicked slide without going through other slides

Comment: Please set $SlideDuration to 0 to reach the goal.

Comment: That works. What if when I set it to 0, I want it to go to selected slide slower than the default speed? (keeping the condition of not going through other slides)

Comment: It will always go through other slides. But the speed relates to $SlideDuration option. If the value of $SlideDuration is 0, it will go to target slide in 0 milliseconds.